# Scan HTML for values with a special character before them

Tags: php

Say I have values on my page, like #100 #246, What I want to do is scan the page for values with a # before them and then alter them to put a hyperlink on it

```
$MooringNumbers = '#!' . $MooringNumbers . ' | ' . '#!' . $row1["Number"];
  }  
    $viewedResult =  '<tr><td>' .$Surname.'</td><td>'.$Title.'</td><td>'.$MooringNumbers . '</td><td>'.$Telephone.'</td><td>' . '<a href="rlayCustomerUpdtForm.php?id='.$id.'">[EDIT]</a></td>'.'<td>'. '<a href="deleteCustomer.php?id='.$id.'">[x]</a></td>'. '</tr>';   preg_replace('/#!(\d\d\d)/', '<a href="update.php?id=${1}">${1}</a>', $viewedResult);
    echo $viewedResult;
```

This is the broken code which doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second Xoc - use PHP manual. The method next to the one he pointed is [preg-replace-callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Just call:

```
preg_replace_callback(
        '/#\d\d\d/',
        create_function(
            // single quotes are essential here,
            // or alternative escape all $ as \$
            '$matches',
            'return strtolower($matches[0]);' //this you replace with what you want to fetch from database
        )
```

EDIT:
Since you want to always perform the same replacement go with Xoc's preg-replace:

```
preg_replace('/#!(\d\d\d)/', '<a href="update.php?id=${1}">${1}</a>', $your_input);
```

Note: I don't have PHP here, so I give no guarantee of this code not wiping your entire hard disk ;)

Comment: What if... html goes like that?
<p><a href="#234">Normal link</a> Normal text, <b>Product price : 450 &#8482;</b></p>.
Here preg_replace wont work like expected...

Comment: Still he has to come with a unique pattern, no matter what solution he uses for replacing...

Comment: @Majki, welcome to Stack Overflow! =) If you have a minute, you should take a look at the [Stack Overflow Markdown help-page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for how to format code *as* code.

Comment: But since you pointed out quite an important example, one could change pattern to /[^&](#\d\d\d)/

Comment: On the other hand - if you can't come up with any unique pattern, but you know that your special code appears only in <a href="HERE"> then you should probably start parsing HTML as shown in posts that Markcial pointed you to.

Comment: @David Thomas, thanks for pointing that function out. Hadn't noticed that one yet.

Comment: All I want is for the PHP to Scan the HTML page for all bits of text labeled #!123 or any other value with #! before it. Then Automatically change it into a link like <a href="update.php?id=123">123</a>

Comment: Hey! So your values are not random, but you always change them the same way. Then stick with what Xoc gave you in his first post.

Comment: Not totally random, but they are so many I just dont want to have to write out all of them, When I would expect there would be something to automatically send it in a GET URL.

Comment: Sadly, it didnt work. My code was still viewed normally. I will post the code which doesnt work so hopefully someone can fix it

Comment: What it looks like is: #!013223  #!233234 even after using Preg_replace

Comment: First: you need to assign the value back to the variable: $viewedResult = preg_replace(...);

Comment: Second: If your codes have 6 digits you have to change your regular expression to : '/#!(\d\d\d\d\d\d)/' or '/#!(\d{6})/'

Comment: I don't understand, please could you explain more?

Comment: The outcome of the Numbers is not upto me, they are just example ones and can have multiple amounts of digits

Comment: The last part of your should go like this: $viewedResult = preg_replace('/#!(\d{3,6})/', '<a href="update.php?id=${1}">${1}</a>', $viewedResult);

Comment: the numbers {3,6} mean that there has to be at least 3 digits and not more than 6 - change as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using regular expressions, see PHP's [preg_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum #300 dolar amet #20';

preg_match_all('/(^|\s)#(\w+)/', $text, $matches);

// Perform you database magic here for each element in $matches[2]
var_dump($matches[2]);

// Fake query result
$query_result = array ( 300 => 'http://www.example1.com', 20 => 'http://www.example2.com');

foreach($query_result as $result_key => $result_value)
{
    $text = str_replace('#'.$result_key, '<a href="'.$result_value.'">'. $result_value . '</a>', $text);
}

var_dump($text);
```

Comment: My values are random, and I do not know what all of them will be as they are pulled down from a database. That page just shows how to do it if I knew what the values were.

Comment: IMHO this articles are relevant and completely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: So each #integer has a URL stored in the database? I would write a regex to find all #s, put the integers in an array, query your database and perform a str_replace() for each array element.

Comment: I added a code example to my original answer that uses the algorithm I described.

Comment: $query_result = array ( 300 => 'http://www.example1.com', 20 => 'http://www.example2.com'); That is the bit that I dont want to use, as my values are random and only need to be submitted like <a href="update.php?id=$THEIDWITH#BEFOREIT"></a>

Comment: Is there any way to automatically convert the Found String with # Before it, to a URL?